# Still images to "live stream"

Tags: javascript, http, web

I would like to to find a way that I can show images that I receive from my an API to show it on web as "live stream". So what I have tried is, that ask a server about image each 50ms with jQuery but its kind of expensive. I have also tried MJPEG solution but it runs slowly.I would like to know if there is otherway to archive this issue?

Some info: API returns real time image snapshot, like a webcamera for instance.

What I want: show the users, the captures images, like a video stream. Or at least feels like.

Comment: "its kinda expensive", expensive in what way? CPU, network?

Comment: @MichielDral yea, both in CPU & Network. I set an interval of 50ms of each call

Comment: Have you tried pushing them with a WebSocket? I guess WebRTC is the obvious choice for this application.

Comment: the only way reducing the network size is pre-processing the images before sending them via API

Comment: Okay, I see. but is there any other way to do it without involving websockets?